# How to replace constants with some method or variable?

Tags: python, arrays, dataset

I have such function, that calculate forced vital capacity by checking the last positive number before negative in dataset sequence:

```
    def FVC(self, data):
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            # checking if there's enough negative values to tell that inspiration started
            if (data[i][1] > 1) and (data[i][2] < 0):
                count += 1
            elif count > 110:
                return data[i-115][1]
            else:
                count = 0
```

The piece of sequence that I'm looking for might look like this (the answer-string here is `[8340.0, 3.0616, 0.0]`):

```
[8280.0, 3.0611, 0.01]
[8290.0, 3.0612, 0.01]
[8300.0, 3.0613, 0.01]
[8310.0, 3.0614, 0.01]
[8320.0, 3.0615, 0.01]
[8330.0, 3.0616, 0.01]
[8340.0, 3.0616, 0.0]
[8350.0, 3.0615, -0.01125]
[8360.0, 3.0614, -0.01125]
[8370.0, 3.0613, -0.01125]
[8380.0, 3.0611, -0.01625]
[8390.0, 3.0609, -0.0275]
[8400.0, 3.0605, -0.033125]
[8410.0, 3.0601, -0.044375]
[8420.0, 3.0595, -0.055625]
[8430.0, 3.0589, -0.06625]
[8440.0, 3.0582, -0.06625]
[8450.0, 3.0575, -0.06625]
[8460.0, 3.0568, -0.0775]
[8470.0, 3.056, -0.0775]
[8480.0, 3.0551, -0.08875]
[8490.0, 3.0541, -0.105]
[8500.0, 3.0527, -0.1325]
[8510.0, 3.051, -0.17125]
[8520.0, 3.0489, -0.21]
[8530.0, 3.0465, -0.24375]
[8540.0, 3.0437, -0.2825]
[8550.0, 3.0406, -0.31]
[8560.0, 3.0371, -0.34312]
[8570.0, 3.0334, -0.37062]
[8580.0, 3.0294, -0.39875]
[8590.0, 3.0251, -0.43125]
[8600.0, 3.0204, -0.47625]
[8610.0, 3.0151, -0.52625]
[8620.0, 3.0091, -0.5975]
```

But also there might be some errors like this:

```
[6860.0, 3.0468, 0.0]
[6870.0, 3.0467, -0.005625]
[6880.0, 3.0466, -0.01125]
[6890.0, 3.0465, -0.01125]
[6900.0, 3.0464, -0.01125]
[6910.0, 3.0463, -0.01125]
[6920.0, 3.0461, -0.01125]
[6930.0, 3.046, -0.01125]
[6940.0, 3.0459, -0.01125]
[6950.0, 3.0457, -0.021875]
[6960.0, 3.0455, -0.021875]
[6970.0, 3.0452, -0.0275]
[6980.0, 3.0449, -0.033125]
[6990.0, 3.0445, -0.033125]
[7000.0, 3.0443, -0.021875]
[7010.0, 3.0441, -0.021875]
[7020.0, 3.0439, -0.021875]
[7030.0, 3.0437, -0.021875]
[7040.0, 3.0435, -0.021875]
[7050.0, 3.0433, -0.01125]
[7060.0, 3.0433, -0.005625]
[7070.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7080.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7090.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7100.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7110.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7120.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7130.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7140.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7150.0, 3.0433, 0.0]
[7160.0, 3.0434, 0.01]
[7170.0, 3.0435, 0.01]
```

As you can see, the only solution for that cases that I found is just to check if there is 100 negative numbers after sought-for value (just because 100 is pretty big number). So my question is how to replace constant 100 with some non-constant value, so my function will be more adaptive?

Comment: I don't think I understood your problem correctly, but why don't you just pass the constant 100 as a variable instead?

Comment: unclear, how `data` is related to your "constant 100"

Comment: @SurajShourie Because that if I have a bigger datset, that contains measurments taken not once per millisecond, but twice and more? So it will broke the whole function, because it is still will be looking after 100 numbers, not 200 or another value

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that's the point -- it's not related. And I don't know how to make it related in a rational way

Comment: Can you add more details for your problem? I feel like it lacks clarity, what are you exactly trying to do, why exactly is the second dataset a bad example...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to simply supply an additional parameter with a default argument. This allows you to run it as intended, but allows the flexibility to adjust if necessary. Something along the lines of --

```
def FVC(self, data, max_data_size: int = 100):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        # checking if there's enough negative values to tell that inspiration started
        if (data[i][1] > 1) and (data[i][2] < 0):
            count += 1
        elif count > max_data_size:
            return data[i - max_data_size][1]
        else:
            count = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I might, one additional question -- as you can see, this function is inside the class: would it be better to supply with additional parameter not the calculating function, but the constructor function of the class?

Comment: @Noerig potentially. It depends on how the class is being utilized -- which only you would know. If a new instance is initialized every time for each data set, then I would agree it makes more sense being an attribute.